# Windows users/groups - Anonymous Logon, Everyone, Guest - what is what?

Tags: windows, users, groups, guest, anonymous

During installing and scheduling connection via DB-links, I've come accross settings permissions for the libraries (DLLs) for the account/group **Everyone** and account/group **ANONYMOUS LOGON**. So far, I always thought that with **Everyone**, every connection/request will have access to the resource. Why do I need to specify anything else (e.g. the **Anonymous logon**)? Also, what is the difference compared to the guest account if there is any?

I did some research before via search engine, but the Q&A forums I visited, did not bring the relevant explanation - what is what, why do I need this and that and how do they differ. Thanks for the intel.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback in form of "-1", but it would be great if You could add the commentary, how to improve the question/what should I change. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP and later, by default, [do not include anonymous logons in the Everyone group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-let-everyone-permissions-apply-to-anonymous-users).  A logon is anonymous if it did not provide a username; guest logons are not anonymous.  In particular, [the guest account *is* a member of the Everyone group](https://blog.varonis.com/the-difference-between-everyone-and-authenticated-users/), though not the Authenticated Users group.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/562922/94065) provides more information about anonymous logons.